# EventListener and Dynamically added MovieClips. (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cc

I'm trying to create a small game (it's more about learning how to than making a compelling game). It can be resumed like this:
User choose a building in a menu and place it on the stage. When clicking on the newly created building, s/he can choose to upgrade it. (For those that play games like Clash of Clans, it's what i'm trying to do). 
I have my menu, and can place buildings without problem, but I can't click on them. 
Here is the beginning of my code:

```
var build:int=0; //variable that defines which building to place on stage

menuBuilding.house.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fnChooseHouse); //when click on House in Building Menu
function fnChooseHouse (e:Event):void{
    build = 1; //building to place is a House.
}

city.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickEvent);

function mouseClickEvent(e: MouseEvent): void {
    if (build == 0) { //if building not chosen, do nothing
        return
    } else if (build == 1) { // if building is a house
        var house1: house = new house();
        addChild(house1); //add instance of the house
        house1.x = stage.mouseX;
        house1.y = stage.mouseY; // place the house where I clicked
        build = 0; //reset the variable.
        house1.mouseChildren=true; //allow instance of house to be clicked.
    }
};
```

My problem is that there is gonna be a lot of houses (and other buildings). I've tried to name them and push them in an array (so I can access them with a for each...in loop), but it doesn't work.

Someone has an idea? (Btw, I'm still learning AS3 as I go, so I'm not using external .as file yet, still in timeline).
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new instance of a house has no click event listener on it, which would be why you "can't" click on it. By setting "mouseChildren" to true might not do anything as this variable might already be true by default.

In the future, how many houses/buildings will you have? If it is many, I'm not sure this path may be the most efficient down the road.

Comment: I had click listener listening to a for each...in loop (the instances were pushed in an array), but it still didn't work. I'm aware this might not be the most efficient way, but it is the only way i could think of with my limited knowledge. If you can think of another way, I'd really appreciate it. Just point me the way, and I'll look it up :) Thanks.

Comment: if you add an event listener to the house1 instance right after you create it, does that do anything?

Comment: that did it. I had to add part of the code given below to make it work. But finally, it works. Only need to figure out how to check if the new building can be added or if the space is already occupied. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To use an array to put your houses, take a look on this example :

```
city.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickEvent);
function mouseClickEvent(e: MouseEvent): void {

    // it's better to use switch than many if
    switch (build){

        case 0 : 

            return;
            break;

        case 1 :    // create a new house

            build = 0;

            // it's better for class name to be capitalized
            var house:House = new House();  
                house.x = stage.mouseX;
                house.y = stage.mouseY;
            addChild(house); 

            // DisplayObjectContainer.mouseChildren : 
            // is used to enable mouse or user input device for the children of the object and It's enabled by default, so you don't need it
            //house.mouseChildren = true;

            // add your house to the houses array
            houses.push(house);

            break;
    }

}

do_some_actions_with_houses();

function do_some_actions_with_houses():void {
    for(var i:int = 0; i < houses.length; i++){
        var house:House = houses[i];
            // add a name to your house
            house.name = 'house_' + i;
            // add an mouce click event listener
            house.addEventListener(
                MouseEvent.CLICK, 
                function(e:MouseEvent):void {
                    trace(e.currentTarget.name);    // gives : house_0, house_1, ...
                }
            )
    }
}
```

I tried with this code to show you how you can use an array to put your objects and then to do some actions with that, It's a simple example which you have to improve and adapt to your project.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it right away. I understand every line, but if you don't mind, could you clarify this one: 'for(var i:int = 0; i < houses.length; i++){' As I understand it, i corresponds to the index of the array (which must be smaller than the length of the array). but what does the i++ means? Sorry to ask, but i'd like to be able to use it again.

Comment: @Jeryl, Of course, there is no problem. `i++` is used to increment `i`, you can write it : `i = i + 1`. For more details about AS3 loops, take a look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/loops.html).